# php variables and forms method POST

Tags: php, html

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/stile.css">

<title>ControlPanel</title>
</head>

<body>
<br>
<div class="titlebarpesiti" style="background-color:#22AEB9">
CONTROLLO SITO
</div>
<br>
<br>
<div class="titlebarpesiti" style="background-color:#22AEB9">
INSERISCI NUOVA FESTA
</div>
<div class="titlebarpesiti">
<form id="richiesta dati" name="richiesta dati" method="POST" action="PHP/Scrittura_dati.php">

<label for="festa">Festa: (NIKITA*NOMEEVENTO) &nbsp;</label><input type="text" name="festa"> <br> <br>
<label for="data">Data: (4 ottobre) &nbsp;</label><input type="text" name="data"><br> <br> 
<label for="luogo">Luogo: (Nikita) &nbsp;</label><input type="text" name="luogo"><br> <br>
<label for="prezzo">Prezzo:(12€) &nbsp;</label><input type="text" name="prezzo"><br> <br>
<label for="organizzatori">FotoNome: (NIKITANOMEEVENTO) &nbsp;</label><input type="text" name="organizzatore"><br> <br>
<label for="linkevento">LinkEvento: (www..) &nbsp;</label><input type="text" name="linkevento"><br> <br>
<label for="numeriPR">PR: (333..) &nbsp;</label><input type="text" name="numeriPR"><br> <br>

<input type="submit" value="Invia Dati"><br> </br>
</form>
</div>

<br>
<div class="titlebarpesiti" style="background-color:#22AEB9">
MODIFICA FESTA
</div>
<div class="titlebarpesiti">
<form id="aggiornamento dati" name="aggiornamento dati" method="POST" action="PHP/Aggiorn_Dati.php">
<label for="ID">INSERISCI ID FESTA &nbsp;</label><input type="text" name="ID"><br> <br>
<label for="festa">Festa: &nbsp;</label><input type="text" name="festa"> <br> <br>
<label for="data">Data: &nbsp;</label><input type="text" name="data"><br> <br> 
<label for="luogo">Luogo: &nbsp;</label><input type="text" name="luogo"><br> <br>
<label for="prezzo">Prezzo: &nbsp;</label><input type="text" name="prezzo"><br> <br>
<label for="organizzatori">Foto: &nbsp;</label><input type="text" name="organizzatore"><br> <br>
<label for="linkevento">LinkEvento: (www..) &nbsp;</label><input type="text" name="linkevento"><br> <br>
<label for="numeriPR">PR: (333..) &nbsp;</label><input type="text" name="listapr"><br> <br>

<input type="submit" value="Invia Dati"><br> </br>


</form>
</div>


<br>

<form>

<br>


<div class="titlebarpesiti" style="background-color:#FF0004">
ELIMINARE DATI
<form id="eliminare dati" name="eliminare dati" method="POST" action="PHP/eliminaredati.php">
<input type="text" name="ideliminare">
<input type="submit" value="INVIO"><br> <br>
</form>
</div>


<br>
<div class="titlebarpesiti" style="background-color:#FF0004">
CONTROLLO DB
<form id="controllo DB" name="controllodb" method="POST" action="controllodb.php">
<input type="submit" value="VAI"><br> <br>
</form>
</div>
<br>

<br>
<div class="titlebarpesiti" style="background-color:#FF0004">
PASSED
<form id="idpassed" name="idpassed" method="POST" action="PHP/passed.php">
<input type="text" name="idpassed"> ID
<input type="text" name="value"> VALORE
<input type="submit" value="VAI"><br> </br>
</form>
</div>
<br>

<br>
<div class="titlebarpesiti" style="background-color:#FF0004">
FESTEINHOME
<form id="idpassed" name="idpassed" method="POST" action="PHP/value.php">
<input type="text" name="idpassed"> ID
<input type="text" name="value"> VALORE
<input type="submit" value="VAI"><br> </br>
</form>
</div>
<br>



</body>
</html>
```

Hi all, i have this code, but i have a problem:
all my form runs correctly, but the form "eliminaredati" doesen't work , it doesen't open the file eliminaredati.php, it remind me to my www.site.org/form.php?ideliminare=(mynumber)
why it doesen't work? help me please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have extra open `<form>` tag before `<div class="titlebarpesiti" style="background-color:#FF0004">`.

Please remove it and try.